# display the images vies one by one

Tags: android

Hi i am working on one kid application in that application i want to show 1+1 =2 ,1+2=3 etc.For this i want tio display the number images one by one .That means fiorst display the 1 after + after some time another number.For this give me some suggestions.Please give me some example code .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your idéa is similar to my application in Android Market called Learn Math, looking like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [skogberg.eu](http://www.skogberg.eu/android/LearnMathWins.png))</sub>
.

I use a `TableLayout` with individual `TableRow`s for the images, like this:

```
<TableRow android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img1" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img2" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img3" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img4" />
</TableRow>
```

The program itself has private variables for the images, which I change on user selections. Initially it might look like this (following the image above):

```
public class LearnMath extends Activity {
    private ImageView img1, img2, img3, img4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
        img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
        img3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img3);
        img4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img4);

        // .png images located in res/drawable folder with lower case names
        img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.six);
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);
        img3.setImageResource(R.drawable.zero);
        img4.setImageResource(R.drawable.equals);
    }
```

I hope this gives you a starting point of your application!

Comment: Thank u for your reply.But i want to display the images on eby one means not in the alignment(layout ) sense.I want to display the images like video ,first one will be displayed after some time "+" and after some time another number like that.R u understand now
"

Comment: If you want to add an animation felling to your software, one might be tempted to put the UI-thread to sleep before showing the next image. However, this is bad coding. Instead take a look at UI timer on this address: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html